# La correcta sintaxis para usar la funcion trim() en un formulario que usa javascript y php

Tags: php, javascript, base-de-datos

Tengo un problema al usar la función `trim`, el problema es modificar el valor de un objeto por una variable que influenciada por la función `trim`.

```
var mat = $("#Name").val().trim();
var opc = $("#Name");
```

A lo que voy es: creé una variable en *javascript* que toma el valor original del objeto, para que con el uso de la función `replace()` modifique el objeto original por el valor de la variable con el `trim`:

```
pru = opc.replace(opc, mat);
```

Pero no me modifica el valor, me arroja el valor de:

```
[Object, object]
```

Les dejo todo el código usado en esta vista de materias:

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $( ".field" ).change(function(e) {
      $( "#save" ).show();
    });

    $( "#save" ).click(function(e) {   
      e.preventDefault();
      var rows = $("#tablegroups tr").length - 3;
      var opc = $("#Name");
      var mat = $("#Name").val().trim();
      pru = opc.replace(opc, mat);
      //console.log("<" + mat+ ">");

      document.getElementById("frm_edit_subject").submit(); 
      //$( "frm_edit_subject" ).submit();
    });

    $( "#cancel" ).click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $form = $('<form action="<?php echo base_url()?>index.php/gabby/materias" method="post"enctype="form-data" />'); 
      $form.appendTo("body").submit();
    });

    $( "#frm_edit_subject" ).validate({
      rules: {
        "Name": {required: true, maxlength: 50},
        "Scope": {required: true,},
        "Status": {maxlength: 1, required: true},               
      }
    });
  });
</script>

<?php
//print_r($materia);
echo '<form id="frm_edit_subject" action="'.base_url().'index.php/gabby/materias" method="post"enctype="form-data" />';
echo '<div class="gbyTable" style="width:480px;margin:15px"><table>';
echo '<tr><td>Campo</td><td>Valor</td></tr>';

if(isset($materia['Subject_ID']))
  echo '<tr><td>ID</td><td>'.(isset($materia['Subject_ID'])?$materia['Subject_ID']:"").'</td></tr>';
  echo '<tr><td>Nivel</td><td>'.$level['Name'].'<input type="hidden" name="Level_ID" value="'.$level['Level_ID'].'"><input type="hidden" name="indx" value="'.$indx.'"></td></tr>';
  echo '<tr><td>Nombre</td><td><input type="text" class="field" name="Name" id="Name" value="'.(isset($materia['Name'])?$materia['Name']:"").'"></td></tr>';
  echo '<tr><td>Ámbito</td><td>'.form_dropdown("Scope", array('' => 'Seleccione','S' => 'Materia','G' => 'Genérica','A' => 'Administrativo',),isset($materia['Scope'])?$materia['Scope']:"", 'class="field"').'</td></tr>';
  echo '<tr><td>Estatus</td><td>'.form_dropdown("Status", array('A' => 'Activo','I' => 'Inactivo'),isset($materia['Status'])?$materia['Status']:"", 'class="field"').'</td></tr>';
  echo '<tr><td style="background:#ddd" align="right" colspan="2"><button id="save" style="display:none">Guardar</button><button id="cancel">Cancelar</button></td></tr>';
  echo '</table></div>';

  if(isset($materia['Subject_ID']))
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="idu" value="'.$materia['Subject_ID'].'">';
  else
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="idi" value="">';
    echo "</form>";
?>
```

Comment: Has probado cambiando `var opc = $("#Name");` por `var opc = $("#Name").val(mat);` ?

Comment: Hola Ivan, aun cambiándolo me sigue marcando que es un objeto, me gustaria convertir ese objeto a un string para mandarlo a la base de datos sin los espacios de los lados

Comment: Es necesario el manejo del PHP para este problema, o corresponde netamente al Javascript/jQuery?

Comment: si es necesario php, por ello estoy llenando las variables en javascript con el valor de los inputs de php

Comment: Te arroja `[Object, object]` porque opc es un objeto `var opc = $("#Name");` no un string

Suponiendo que opc fuera un string no tendría caso hacer un replace de si mismo por otra cadena `pru = opc.replace(opc, mat);` ya que internamente está haciendo comparaciones y al final es lo mismo hacer una asignación `pru = mat` y es mucho mas recomendable

Comment: Hola Lato, gracias por la respuesta, te comento que se me prendio el foco y aplique esto quitando las variables opc, mat y la parte donde reemplazo las variables. quedo de esta manera mas simple:    $("#Name").val($("#Name").val().trim());     ya quedo resuelta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

les comento que he hecho algunas modificaciones al codigo, iba por un camino muy dificil, converti el object a string mediante JSON, hasta que opte por tirar todo lo que tenia hecho y eliminando las variables mat, opc, res. hice uso de algo mas simple como es:

```
$("#Name").val($("#Name").val().trim());
```

el codigo quedo de la manera:

```
<script>

$(function () {
    $(".field").change(function (e) {
        $("#save").show();
    });
    $("#save").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var rows = $("#tablegroups tr").length - 3;


        $("#Name").val($("#Name").val().trim());


        //console.log("<" + mat+ ">");

        document.getElementById("frm_edit_subject").submit();


        // $( "frm_edit_subject" ).submit();

    });
    $("#cancel").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $form = $('<form action="<?php echo base_url() ?>index.php/gabby/materias" method="post"enctype="form-data" />');
        $form.appendTo("body").submit();
    });
    $("#frm_edit_subject").validate({
        rules: {
            "Name": {required: true, maxlength: 50},
            "Scope": {required: true, },
            "Status": {maxlength: 1, required: true},
        }
    });
});

</script>

<?php
//print_r($materia);
echo '<form id="frm_edit_subject" action="' . base_url() . 
'index.php/gabby/materias" method="post"enctype="form-data" />';
echo '<div class="gbyTable" style="width:480px;margin:15px"><table>';
echo '<tr><td>Campo</td><td>Valor</td></tr>';
if (isset($materia['Subject_ID']))
echo '<tr><td>ID</td><td>' . (isset($materia['Subject_ID']) ? 
$materia['Subject_ID'] : "") . '</td></tr>';
echo '<tr><td>Nivel</td><td>' . $level['Name'] . '<input type="hidden" 
name="Level_ID" value="' . $level['Level_ID'] . '"><input type="hidden" 
name="indx" value="' . $indx . '"></td></tr>';
echo '<tr><td>Nombre</td><td><input type="text" class="field" name="Name" 
id="Name" value="' . (isset($materia['Name']) ? $materia['Name'] : "") . '">
</td></tr>';
echo '<tr><td>Ámbito</td><td>' . form_dropdown("Scope", array('' => 
'Seleccione', 'S' => 'Materia', 'G' => 'Genérica', 'A' => 
'Administrativo',), isset($materia['Scope']) ? $materia['Scope'] : "", 
'class="field"') . '</td></tr>';
echo '<tr><td>Estatus</td><td>' . form_dropdown("Status", array('A' => 
'Activo', 'I' => 'Inactivo'), isset($materia['Status']) ? $materia['Status'] 
: "", 'class="field"') . '</td></tr>';
echo '<tr><td style="background:#ddd" align="right" colspan="2"><button 
id="save" style="display:none">Guardar</button><button 
id="cancel">Cancelar</button></td></tr>';
echo '</table></div>';
if (isset($materia['Subject_ID']))
echo '<input type="hidden" name="idu" value="' . $materia['Subject_ID'] . 
'">';
else
echo '<input type="hidden" name="idi" value="">';
echo "</form>";
?>
```

Comment: ¿Esa es la solución a tu problema? Si lo es, no olvides marcarla como __aceptada__.

Comment: Utiliza el enlace [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/92848/edit)   en tu pregunta para añadir información adicional. El botón Publicar respuesta se debe usar solamente para respuestas completas a la pregunta. Si esto es una respuesta te sugiero revises: [answer]

Answer (score -1):

te envio un ejemplo eh jScript simple espero te sirva.

```
var opc = "    Hola Mundo!    ";
alert("-" + opc +"-"  );
alert("-" + opc.trim() +"-"  );

var str = "Visit Microsoft!";
alert(str);
alert(str.replace("Microsoft", "W3Schools"));
```

Comment: hola user, y en el caso que quiera usar objetos?? he leido que la funcion replace no permite modificar el valor si se usan objetos, lo que quiero es convertir esos objetos a string